# Cloud Removal through Sen2cor for sentinel 2 images?

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, sen2cor

I have this imagery for an area of germany. According to docs of Sen2Cor, it states it can only remove haze and light clouds, i wanted to ask would it be possible to remove something as dense as shown in the imagery with the processor?

How can i perform cloud correction on such imageries without losing data below?

[image: Sentinel 2 Image]

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a single image you won't be able to create a cloudfree image, because there is just no data sensed below the cloud. You will need other cloud free images and mosaic the clouds.